# How to hide all answers once "Enter" button is clicked?

Tags: javascript

I created a quiz using a drop-down list, and used:

```
function fadeAnswer(){
$(this).next('.answer').toggle("slow");
$(this).toggleClass('close');
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {

$('.answer').hide();
$('.main h2').click(fadeAnswer);

  }); 

  function endend ()
  { 

$('.answer').hide();

   }
```

I also have an "Enter" button at the end of my quiz, and I wanted to have all of the open drop-down tabs close once the "Enter" button was clicked on. How can I do that? I figured I should make a function that contains:

```
$('.answer').hide();
```

and link that to the onclick event, but that didn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show us the code where you tried to make it an onclick event? Seems you are on the right track, probably missing something small.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious as to why your logic didn't work for you. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cUsf4/) is a simple demo using what you described and it should work fine.

```
$("#enter").click(function() {
    $(".answer").hide();
});
```